# Java - Cannot find symbol...?

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

```
public class Temperatur{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int[] temp = {0, 2, 2, 8, 12, 16, 21, 16, 21, 16, 12, 8, 4, 2};
        method1(temp);
    }
    static int method1(int[] array){
        int number= 0;
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            number = number + array[i];
        }
    return number();
    }
}
```

I get error: Cannot find Symbol, its pointing at "return number();" and I have no idea why... help?

Comment: replace `return number();` with `return number;`

Comment: What do you think `number()` is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

`number` is a variable, not a method.
Therefore `return number();` should be `return number;`.